# Using the output of an ajax function in another ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

The overview of what Im doing:
1-User creates a template consisting of different elements
2-He Presses a button:

*first ajax function creates a new entry in the custom template database

*second ajax  function take the id of the template and saves all the elements in a second database with that Id as a foreign key.

**FIRST AJAX**

```
var data1 = {}

        data1.ID = "1";
        data1.RName = '<%= Session["Name"] %>';
        data1.RType = '<%= Session["RType"] %>';
        data1.SType = '<%= Session["SType"] %>';

        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebService1.asmx/AddT") %>',
            data: JSON.stringify(data1),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                console.log(result);



            },  
            failure: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Status: " + jqXHR.status + "; Error: " + jqXHR.responseText); // Display error message  
            }
        });
```

And this is the webservice it calls.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

    public int AddT(string ID,string RName, string RType, string SType)
    {


        int id1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(ID)));



        Models2.CustomTemplate itemo2 = new Models2.CustomTemplate
        {
            Id = id1,
            Name = RName,
            ReportType = RType,
            StudyType = SType

        };



        using (TestEntities db2 = new TestEntities())
        {
            db2.CustomTemplates.Add(itemo2);
            db2.SaveChanges();

        }

        int id2 = itemo2.Id;

        Session["TheID"] = id2;

        return id2;

    }
```

It simply creates the template, And I make a session variable with the ID I need.

**SECOND AJAX**

The second ajax is inside a loop

```
$(".Type1").each(function (i, e) {[…]}
```

simply looping through all the elements and adding them to their database (each with its own ajax function)

```
var data = {};

            data.ID = "2";
            data.InitialID = Lid;
            data.Xpos = Xcoord;
            data.Ypos = Ycoord;
            data.Itemwidth = object1.width;
            data.Itemheight = object1.height;
            data.CTid = '<%= Session["TheID"] %>';
```

Here you see how I try to pass the output of the previous ajax through the session variable (I also tried making a normal variable but it did not work as well)

```
$.ajax({

                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebService1.asmx/AddItemo") %>',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    console.log(result);
                },
                failure: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Status: " + jqXHR.status + "; Error: " + jqXHR.responseText); // Display error message  
                }
            });
```

and the webservice it calls:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

    public Item2 AddItemo(string ID, string InitialID, string Xpos, string Ypos, string Itemwidth, string Itemheight, string CTid)
    {

        int id1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(ID)));
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(InitialID)));
        int w = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(Itemwidth)));
        int h = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(Itemheight)));
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(Xpos)));
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(Ypos)));
        int cusID = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(CTid)));


        Models2.Item2 itemo2 = new Models2.Item2
        {
            Id = id1,
            InitialID = id,
            Itemwidth = w,
            Itemheight = h,
            Xpos = x,
            Ypos = y,
            TemplateID = cusID

        };

        using (TestEntities db2 = new TestEntities())
        {
            db2.Item2.Add(itemo2);
            db2.SaveChanges();

        }


        return itemo2;

    }
```

The problem is that as the ajax is asynchronous, the variable I try to pass is not ready so it gives me an internal error 500:

```
ExceptionType:"System.FormatException"
Message:"Input string was not in a correct format."
```

I tried anything I could find :

1- Setting all ajax with

```
async:false,
```

2- using the .done on the first ajax

```
 $.ajax({}).done(ajax2)
```

3-$.when(ajax1).then(ajax2);

4- putting the second ajax in the success function of the first.

5-putting it in the complete function of the first ajax

6-adding a delay with setinterval

Im thinking of creating the template, redirecting to a second page where I call the second ajax.

Please help me,
I've been stuck on this for a few days.

Comment: @a-j-alhorr there are really lots of text, hard to understand what's your problem... And don't think we need BE side code (just remove it). As I understand, you just need two sequential ajax requests (and make some stuff in the last request). Is that correct?

Comment: Hello yes, I need sequential ajax requests, but the second one feeds on the post-back of the first one. And Im sorry, but what is BE code? Thank you @Ilia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check **Network** panel in Chrome DevTools.

1. Is all the XHR send successfully?
2. Is all the XHR request params & response body correctly?

> If you are not familiar with this, it is really recommended you to Copy/Paste your XHR here by doing following steps:
>
> 1. **Right click** on the selected XHR item in Network panel in Chrome DevTools;
> 2. select **Copy** => **Copy as fetch** and **Copy response**.

Here is a simple Pseudo code which can solve your situation.

```
// first ajax
$.ajax({
  url: firstAjaxURL,
  success: function (result) {
    // you can get the database ID from "result"
    console.log(result.id);

    $(".Type1").each(function (i, e) {
      // second ajax can take the "result.id" as params
      $.ajax({
        url: secondAjaxURL,
        params: {id: result.id},
        success: function (secondResult) {
          console.log(secondResult);
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

As the ugly code above, when the later ajax need first ajax's response content as params, the code above take callback function inside a callback function and inside a callback function. What if you need 3 or more ajax in a chain? This problem called "Callback Hell". The solutions to solve "Callback Hell" are: Promise, generator, async/await. You can Google it.

Comment: you can check promises chain as possible example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjbMRM?editors=0012)